# log4j not working together with Spring at all

Tags: java, spring, log4j

I use **log4j config**:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,INFO, stdout

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.conversionPattern=%d{dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss} %5p - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.encoding=UTF-8
```

In Spring controller I use:

```
  private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AppController.class);
```

But it;s not shown in console when trying to:

```
logger.debug("text");
```

How to fix it?

**UPDATE**

AppController class imports:

```
import app.model.XmlRequest;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.util.*;
import static app.service.Helper.*;
```

Comment: Can you show the `import` s from Logger class?

Comment: Where's your `log4j.properties` placed?

Comment: in `resources` folder

Comment: Are there slf4j bindings in your classpath?

Comment: I am not sure about that

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting the log level to INFO, debug messages wont show up. Change the first line of log4j.properties to:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout
```